# регулярка для одной буквы(только!)

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Не могу понять, какую регулярку использовать ТОЛЬКО для одной буквы. Допустим строка: "Мама мыла раму в доме у папы 123 34,5". Какая регулярка служит для нахождения (в) и (у). (\w?) - ищет все буквы(как и ([a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\s])).

Comment: Наверное хочешь найти все что между этими буквами? Или нет?

Comment: `(начало или не-буква)(буква)(не-буква или конец)` Во второй группе либо набор нужных букв, либо шаблон любых букв.

Comment: Наверно не правильно выразился. Нужно найти НЕ слово и НЕ число.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var str = "hallow hallow g g gg 1 df";

var arr = str.split(" ");
arr = arr.filter(x=>x.length == 1 && x.match("[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z]"));

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Comment: Не. Эта регулярка просто находит все буквы. В слове или не в слове.

Comment: @DmitriyKruglov Находит только буквы окружённые пробелами. Если окружена чем-то кроме пробелов, то это надо тоже в параметрах split-а указать.

Comment: @DmitriyKruglov нет, в слове не находит, смотрите функцию `split` перед ней. Она делает разбиение.

Comment: Действительно. не обратил внимание на split.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл нормальное решение через регулярное выражение.
Надо было использовать поиск назад `"?<="` и поиск вперёд `"?="`, они участвуют в поиске, но не включаются в текущий найденный токен.

```
"(?<= |^)([a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ])(?= |$)"
```

тестируем тут - https://regex101.com/r/ul6mSu/3

Answer (score -1):

Вот это выражение `(?:[^\wа-яйё]|^)(?:[а-яА-Я]((?:[^\wа-яйё]+[а-яА-Я])?)+)(?:[^\wа-яйё]|$)` может захватить все, но захватывает по 2+ буквы, если они разделены не буквой. Может понадобиться дополнительная обработка

Comment: данная строка была примером. Мне не нужно найти конертно в или у! Нужно найти вхождения любой буквы. Не слова, а именно буквы

Comment: Самое интересно что не все однобуквы захватываются... сам не могу понять как сделать что бы попали все. Вот ваш пример https://regex101.com/r/gmgQcw/1 , смотрим что вторая п не попала.

Comment: Первый match захватывае пробел в конце него, и поэтому если сразу после идёт однабуква, то она уже не входит так как пробел захвачен предыдущим совпадением.

Comment: Теперь для трёх однобукв подряд не работает. Сам не знаю как одной регуляторкой решить.

Comment: По идее может в регуляторках возможно есть какой-то способ что бы следующее совпадение начинал искать не с конца предъидущего а с отступом... так как такую задачу на стеке уже не раз вижу, но когда отвечал на подобную так и не нашёл решения.